# Jmeter making application/json create account tests

Tags: json, playframework, jmeter

Hello I'm trying to test my application speed between play framework 2.2.1 version and play 2.3.1 version using Jmeter. I have already configured it and it works good but I don't know how I can send a lot of json objects to test it for example 100 data.

My function take json object which looks like

```
{"username":"xxx","email":"xxx@ee.null","password":"yyy"}
```

Is here anyway that I can request more than only one json? I mean I want to create around 100 accounts not only one to have better chart.

I was searching for it and was testing some resolutions but none of them worked for me.
Is here any way to make file like:

```
{"username":"aaa","email":"aaa@ee.null","password":"yyy"}
{"username":"bbb","email":"bbb@ee.null","password":"yyy"}
{"username":"ccc","email":"ccc@ee.null","password":"yyy"}
```

Which will create 3 accounts in one "start" ?

I will be very thankful for every help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for the way to kick off all requests which create accounts at exactly the same time you can use [Synchronizing Timer](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer) for this.